# bootstrap 5 carousel doesn't work in Blazor

Tags: javascript, jquery, blazor, carousel, bootstrap-5

please open the below link to see the carousel that is working with the help of jquery and bootstrap 4.3.1 (code lines 48,50). Instead of these, I wanted to use Bootstrap 5 js files to get the same carousel. But it doesn't with code lines (8), 52-54 (bootstrap 5 CSS and JS will make a gap between the images sliding in the carousel, which is not a requirement. Firstly, with Bootstrap 5 CSS and JS in blazor, the images won't slide by themself or when clicked on Next/prev buttons, so need to click on carousel-indicators to see the slide function)

**Bootstrap 5 is at least sliding in JS Editor but with white gaps while sliding even here:**
[JS Fiddle][https://jsfiddle.net/gxyuqoer/]

**Bootstrap 5 is not working in Blazor editor:**
[Blazor Fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/2ez7axaj)

Kindly let me understand what is the difference between the bootstrap 4.3.1 and 5 version's carousel and why its not possible to get the carousel sliding in version 5

Comment: Seems to be working for me the animations stops of course if the mouse is hovering an image. You may be missing the initial call to start it though.

Comment: Not sure why you have three bootstrap js libraries referenced! You reference 4.x bootstrap CSS but add 4.x, 5.x bundle and 5.x non-bundled!

Comment: hi @BrianParker, the problem is seen when you comment the line 7 and uncomment line 8, which is using bootstrap 5.0 instead of 4.3 version CSS. Also, I think it is natural for a carousel to stop the animations when the mouse is hovered (in 4.3 and above versions)

Comment: Hi @Quango, I was just trying which JS in bootstrap 5 supports the same functioning as in the bootstrap 4.3 version. But it was not working for me :(

Comment: I had a lot of issues using a Bootstrap 5 Carousel as well. I ended up using a BlazorStrap carousel and it worked really well for what I wanted: https://blazorstrap.io/carousels

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [HxCarousel](https://havit.blazor.eu/components/HxCarousel) component from HAVIT Blazor (https://havit.blazor.eu) bundle.

Free, built on top of Bootstrap 5.

If you are not willing to use the bundle, you can clone the source code (https://github.com/havit/Havit.Blazor), it is open-source.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this javascript in your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myCarousel = document.querySelector('#IndexCarousel');
    var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarousel);
</script>
```